# what are the alternative methods to replace SSRS Subscription?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, architecture

We have a requirement to remove SSR dependancy as well as SQL jobs dependancy from our distributes system and have to implement alternative solution to send subscriptions from our system.Main target is to move database into noSql database.Problem is noSQL databases don't have sql jobs kind of functionality as well as SSRS subscription functionality.we have to implement solution using c# because whole system runs on windows server. can anyone suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Quartz.net for job sheduling.Follow this tutorial to learn Quartz.net

[Quartz.net Tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1222/put-the-cloud-to-work-pt-1-create-a-background-worker-using-quartznet)